# error : Invalid Mex-file in MATLAB R2013a

Tags: matlab, mex

I have tried to use a system object in order to find a transformation matrix corresponding to the matching point pairs using RANSAC algorithm, and an error of "Mex file entry point is missing.  Please check the (case-sensitive) 
spelling of mexFunction" was shown. what shall I do? Here is the code :

```
geoTransformEst = vision.GeometricTransformEstimator; % defaults to RANSAC

% Configure the System object.
geoTransformEst.Transform = 'Nonreflective similarity';
geoTransformEst.NumRandomSamplingsMethod = 'Desired confidence';
geoTransformEst.MaximumRandomSamples = 1000;
geoTransformEst.DesiredConfidence = 99.8;

% Invoke the step() method on the geoTransformEst object to compute the
% transformation from the distorted to the original image. You
% may see varying results of the transformation matrix computation because
% of the random sampling employed by the RANSAC algorithm.
[tform_matrix inlierIdx] = step(geoTransformEst, matchedDistorted.Location, ...
    matchedOriginal.Location);
```

I am using MATLAB R2013a on 32-bit  Windows.

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message. What line of code causes the error? What is the MEX-file that doesn’t work? Where did you get it from?

Comment: I fixed the problem. I just installed the MEX-file by choosing the version and the directory with a simple MATLAB line. @CrisLuengo Thnx .